# OGC: Retrieve all layers with given column name

Tags: wfs, ogc, getcapabilities

I have a given column name `city` and a list of layers from a `GetCapabilities` on an OGC server request. Is there a way to get all of the layers that have a column called `city` without sending a request for each layer?

My ultimate goal would be to provide something like a query box for a user where they can enter `city = springfield` and come back with all of the results from the layers that have a column called `city`.

Comment: Do you read GetCapabilities from a WFS service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no option but to make a `describeFeature` request on each layer listed in the `getCapabilities` response. This should be reasonably fast as you are asking for just the descriptions and you can cache the responses.

Comment: But I guess I can do that in a comma separated list in a single request, which wouldn't be too bad I guess. `&typename=AK_cities,AL_cities...` 
Thanks!